# ReportScore GameCenter method not found

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center

I am trying to upload my scores for my game to Gamecenter, however I cannot write code to do that without getting errors. Also, it says that there is no class method for reportScores:scores. I am not sure how to implement that into the Gamecenter Class.

```
-(void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forLeaderboardID: @"tap_amateur" identifier

{

    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:@"tap_amateur"];

    scoreReporter.value = score;

    scoreReporter.context = 0;



    NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];

    [GKLeaderboard reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {


    }];   

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
[GKLeaderboard reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {


}];
```

to:

```
[GKLeaderboard reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(NSError* error) {

         [self setLastError:error];

         BOOL success = (error == nil);

         if ([_delegate
              respondsToSelector:
              @selector(onScoresSubmitted:)]) {

             [_delegate onScoresSubmitted:success];
         }
     }];
```